# what is correct approach to make a check for if statements to append the value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have url call that needs to be prepared before we make a request to backend , there is baseurl but some url needs additonal params 
that needs to be added to url e.g servicetocall/additonalParam. Now it is working as expected but problem is when i have query param that are part of url 
and takes multiple values e.g lets say i have baseurl define as `servicetoCall?configlist=` and i have to assign values `login,validation`. 
if i send these values it appear as `servicetoCall?configlist=/login,validation` but in this case i dont want `/` . How to make that check and resolve 
this issue ?

main.ts

```
cont params = ["login,validation", "additonal param if needed"]

if (serviceName.params && serviceName.length > 0) {
    serviceName.params.forEach((param) => {
       baseConfig.Url += "/" + param.toString();
    });
}

if(serviceName = "servicetoCall?configlist=") {
    serviceName.params.forEach((param) => {
       baseConfig.Url += param.toString();
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good case for using [URL.searchParams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

Comment: is it possible provide some example with above code ?

Comment: Add params using that API then check `if(urlObject.searchParams.has('someKey'))`

Comment: Is this an [tag:angular] component or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "[HttpClient GET](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get)". (or the POST or DELETE Version it´s allways very similar)

You could manipulate the URL all by yourself and then call it

```
const url = 'myUrl?param1="Hello"&param2="World"'
this.http.get(url)
```

That´s what you are doing now.

Or you could use the Angular Objects and do let Angular do the work.

```
const url:string = 'myUrl';
const options = {
  params: { 
    param1: 'Hello',
    param2: 'World'
  }
}
this.http.get( url, options);
```

This looks like a lot more code, BUT it´s also more clearly whaty our are doing. Your intention is shown. There is a fixed url part, there are params...

Last, but not least, you can prepare a [HttpRequest](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest) object, and sent it with

```
this.http.request( yourRequest );
```

But this is mostly just the long way of the version i showed before.

Just a few words, why i would choose the way with a seperate "option" object, instead of an allmighty url string...
If you pack everything directly into the string, it is will be quite hard to manipulate later. So, this way is okay if it is a very easy url. As soon as it gets slightly complicated or you think about "preparing" an url for later use, i would instantly wrap some sugar around it (HttpClient is your friend here). 
This makes your code more readable and you can test it easily

warm regards